# How can I Select nth element from an array's 2nd dimension?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a 2-dimensional int array, and I'd like to get the 2nd element from every array in the 2nd dimension. So for example, I'd like to get 2,4, and 6 from the array literal `'{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}'`. Is this possible? I've searched the docs but I haven't found anything that can do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unnest(arr[:][2:2])` will give you a table expression for what you want (where `arr` is the name of your array column)

If you want to get a 1 dimensional array of those elements, you can use `array(select * from unnest(arr[:][2:2]))` (because `arr[:][2:2]` is still a 2 dimensional one).

http://rextester.com/VLOJ18858